# Property does not exist on type error when switching from JS to TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello I have recently made the decision to switch from JS to TS for better coding but I am getting these errors from TypeScript, `Validate` function works perfectly fine in JavaScript.

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type '{ isValid: boolean; user: string; userLowercase: string; } | undefined'
Property 'userLowercase' does not exist on type '{ isValid: boolean; user: string; userLowercase: string; } | undefined'
```

These are the files

```
//functions.ts
function Validate(arg) {
    if (!arg) return
    let query :string = arg.toString().replace("@", "")
    let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/
    let isValid = regex.test(query)
    if (!isValid) return
    let userLowercase :string = query.toLowerCase()
    return { isValid: true, user : query, userLowercase }
}

//firstCommand.ts 
import { Validate } from './functions'

class firstCommand extends Commands {
    async command() {
        if (!Validate(this.arg)) return
        const { user, userLowercase } = Validate(this.arg)
        ///
    }
}
```

I have searched on Google but no one seem to have the same problem ?
Am I writing the code wrong and how can I fix this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The value can be undefined. There are no properties on undefined. Check if it is not an undefined before proceeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error tells you what is wrong:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type
  '{ isValid: boolean; user: string; userLowercase: string; } | undefined'
```

Note the last bit `| undefined`. That means the the type of your variable could be the value you expect, or it might be `undefined`. If the value actually is `undefined`, then your program would crash here.

The problem is your `Validate()` function. It has this line:

```
if (!arg) return
```

And this line:

```
if (!isValid) return
```

So if `arg` or `isValid` are falsy, the function returns `undefined`. It only return the full object if it makes past those early return statements.

All that means that the return type of your function is:

```
{ isValid: boolean; user: string; userLowercase: string; } | undefined
```

---

To fix this you must test the value for existence before you treat this value as if it exists.

```
const validationResult = Validate(this.arg)
if (validationResult) {
  const { user, userLowercase } = validationResult
  // proceed...
}
```

Typescript will notice that you checked the variable for existence, and let you proceed from inside that `if` statement.

Comment: This seemed totally logical explanation but when I tried it in the code and it still prompts me the error [as shown here](https://i.imgur.com/i25aVJu.png). I tried to remove some if duplicate and unnecessary code from `Validate` function but it does not seem to care

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer had a typo. Note that the variable that is used _must_ be the variable that was checked. `const { user, userLowercase } = validationResult`

Comment: Oh well! Works fine now! Nevermind my previous comment then, I thank you very much, I will look more into types regarding these probable errors